Quiver relations in GAP / QPA, constant paths
I want to work with a quiver algebra with relations containing constant paths, but it doesn't work.
So for example, if I work with a quiver with one vertex and one loop:
LoadPackage("qpa");
Q := Quiver(["v"],[["v","v","a"]])
kQ := PathAlgebra(Rationals, Q);
AssignGeneratorVariables(kQ);

then if I create this algebra:
relations := [a*a];
A := kQ/relations;

everything is fine, but I want to do something like this:
relations := [a*a - v];
A:= kQ/relations;

but then I get this error:
and each summand of each element is not (only) a constant
times a vertex.
Error, first argument must be a ring,
second argument must be a list of generators at /opt/gap-v4.12.2/.libs/../lib/ideal.gi:25 called from
Ideal( KQ, gb ) at /opt/gap-v4.12.2/.libs/../pkg/qpa/lib/pathalg.gi:2064 called from
<function "/ for PathAlgebra and a list of generators">( <arguments> )
 called from read-eval loop at *stdin*:17
you can 'quit;' to quit to outer loop, or
you can 'return;' to continue

How to work around this?

This section of the QPA manual is probably helpful.

For those, like me, who have never encountered this concept : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quiver_(mathematics)

QPA is designed to deal with admissible ideals in path algebras, that is, ideals contained in the square of the ideal $J$ generated by all the arrows and containing some power $J^t$. However, you can circumvent this by doing the following:
Q := Quiver( [ "v" ], [ [ "v", "v", "a" ] ] );
kQ := PathAlgebra( Rationals, Q );
AssignGeneratorVariables( kQ );
relations := [ a*a - v ];
I := Ideal( kQ, relations );
els := ReducedListQPA(MakeUniform(relations), kQ);
gb := [];

while Length(els) > 0 do
  for el in els do
    el_tip := Tip(el);
    Add(gb, el/TipCoefficient(el_tip));
  od;
  
  n := Length(gb);
  els := [];
  
  for i in [1..n] do
    x := TipWalk(gb[i]);
    k := Length(x);
    
    for j in [1..n] do
      y := TipWalk(gb[j]);
      l := Length(y);
      
      for r in [Maximum(0, k-l)..k-1] do
        if x{[r+1..k]} = y{[1..k-r]} then
          b := x{[1..r]};
          c := y{[k-r+1..l]};
          
          overlap := gb[i]*Product(c, One(kQ)) - Product(b, One(kQ))*gb[j];
          remainder := RemainderOfDivision(overlap, gb, kQ);
          
          if not IsZero(remainder) then
            AddSet(els, remainder);
          fi;
        fi;
      od;
    od;
  od;
od;

gb := TipReducedList( gb, kQ );
gb := ReducedListQPA( gb, kQ );

GroebnerBasis( I, gb );
A := kQ / I;
Dimension(A);
B := BasisVectors( Basis( A ) );
B[ 2 ] * B[ 2 ];

However, after this point you "travel at your own risk". Many function will now not work applied to $A$.
I hope that these comments are helpful - The QPA-team.
